# why add to menu box disabled in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

while adding menus in WordPress add to menu box is disabled.So I can't add menus in WordPress (but in demo link it is working properly when it's live menu is facing kind of problem)
[image]
menu box is disabled here

Answer (score 0):

Menu box is not disable you have to create menu first then Add menu will be active.

Step 1: 
Go to  Appearance -> Menu.

Step 2:
Add menu name in text box "Main menu" and hit Create menu  button.

Step 3:
Select created menu from drop-down list.

Step 4 : 
Choose menu item from list of pages display on left side.

Step 5 :
Press Add to Menu button.

Step 6:

Press Save Menu button.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose which pages at the left side that you want to add under menu. Just click the checkbox and you will see the pages at the right side.

[image: You have to choose which pages that you want to add under menu.]